Порядок объектов при перегрузке арифметических операторов
допустим, мне для чего-то нужно сделать свой класс, в котором я неким образом (не влияя на логику арифметических операций) добавляю что-нибудь.
def __mul__(self, other):
   ....
   return self * other

a = Class(10)

a * 10 # 100

но что-делать, если я хочу переставить множители

10 * a # unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Class'


Такая ошибка логична, но крайне не удобна - потому что в разных формулах приходится учитывать порядок множителей.
Есть ли варианты обойти эту проблему?

вы  делали проверку, что other это int? к примеру, if isinstance(other, int): #решение else: #ошибка

@StanislavVolodarskiy, ответы - в ответы.

Определите __rmul__(self, other) чтобы поддержать умножение вида 10 * a.

Ого, так легко. Оказалось. спасибо. В следующий раз постараюсь тщательнее изучать вопрос перед тем как задать его)
